# How to update table records, but only form fields that have data in them?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-routing, laravel-controller

In my controller, I have my create record method, but I want to edit existing records, but only update the fields that are filled out. I try to only fill out one or two fields on the edit property file, but no matter what field I fill out, it returns the same error:

> Attempt to assign property "property_title" on null

---

Update method in my controller:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        // Find the record
        $prop = Property::find($id);

        if ($request->hasFile('prop_img')) {
            $file = $request->file('prop_img');

           $filenameWithExtension = $file->getClientOriginalName();

            $Extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();

            $filenameOnly = pathinfo($filenameWithExtension, PATHINFO_FILENAME);

            $filename = $filenameOnly . time() . '.' . $Extension;

           $file->move('property_images', $filename);

            $prop->property_image = $filename;
         }

        $prop->property_title = $request->input('prop_title');
        $prop->property_description = $request->input('prop_desc');
        $prop->bedrooms = $request->input('prop_beds');
        $prop->bathrooms = $request->input('prop_baths');
        $prop->square_feet = $request->input('prop_ft');
        $prop->finished_basement = $request->input('prop_basement');
        $prop->prop_tax = $request->input('prop_tax');
        $prop->heat_type = $request->input('prop_heat');
        $prop->water_heater = $request->input('prop_waterheater');
        $prop->year_built = $request->input('prop_year');

        $prop->save();
        return view('admin.properties');
    }
```

---

Routes:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function() {

    Route::get('/', function() {
        return view('admin.dashboard');
    })->name('admin')->middleware('auth');

    Route::get('/properties', [PropertiesController::class, 'index'])->name('all-properties')->middleware('auth');
    Route::get('/properties/create', [PropertiesController::class, 'create'])->middleware('auth');
    Route::post('/properties/store-property', [PropertiesController::class, 'store'])->name('admin.store_properties')->middleware('auth');
    Route::get('/properties/delete/{id}', [PropertiesController::class, 'destroy'])->middleware('auth');
    
    // Edit property
    Route::get('/properties/edit/{id}', [PropertiesController::class, 'edit'])->name('admin.edit')->middleware('auth');
    Route::post('/properties/update/{id}', [PropertiesController::class, 'update'])->middleware('auth');

});
```

---

Edit properties blade file:

```
@extends( 'layouts.admin' )

@section( 'content' )
<h1 class="admin-header">Edit Listing</h1>
@if($errors->any())
<h4>{{$errors->first()}}</h4>
@endif
<form method="POST" action="/admin/properties/update/{id}" class="add_edit_property_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <div>
        <label for="prop_title">Property Title</label>
        <input type="text" name="prop_title" id="prop_title" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="prop_desciption">Property Description</label>
        <textarea name="prop_desc" id="prop_desc"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="prop_img">Property Image</label>
        <input type="file" name="prop_img" id="prop_img" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="prop_beds">Number of Bedrooms</label>
        <input type="number" name="prop_beds" id="prop_beds" steps="1" min="1" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="prop_baths">Number of Bathrooms</label>
        <input type="number" name="prop_baths" id="prop_baths" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="prop_ft">Sqaure Feet</label>
        <input type="number" name="prop_ft" id="prop_ft" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="props_basement">Finished Basement?</label>
        <select name="prop_basement" id="prop_basement">
            <option value="" selected disabled>Select an option</option>
            <option value="yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="no">No</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="prop_tax">Property Tax</label>
        <input type="number" name="prop_tax" id="prop_tax" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="props_heat">Heat Type</label>
        <select name="prop_heat" id="prop_heat">
            <option value="" selected disabled>Select an option</option>
            <option value="gas">Gas</option>
            <option value="oil">Oil</option>
            <option value="electric">Electric</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="props_waterheater">Finished Basement?</label>
        <select name="prop_waterheater" id="prop_waterheater">
            <option value="" selected disabled>Select an option</option>
            <option value="yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="no">No</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="prop_year">Year Built</label>
        <input type="number" name="prop_year" id="prop_year" />
    </div>

    <button type="submit">Add New Listing</button>

</form>

@endsection
```

Edit method code:

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        return view('admin.edit_property');

    }
```

---

**Results of var_dump**

var_dump($id):

`string(5) "{$id}"`

var_dump($request::all()):

`array(8) { ["_token"]=> string(40) "9QOxw20xoy1mEDD6BTWZEJtMpgl3rC16ACejvtcU" ["prop_title"]=> string(4) "Test" ["prop_desc"]=> NULL ["prop_beds"]=> NULL ["prop_baths"]=> NULL ["prop_ft"]=> NULL ["prop_tax"]=> NULL ["prop_year"]=> NULL }`

$prop = Property::find($id);
var_dump($prop):

`NULL`

Comment: you are passing `{id}` via the URL ... you probably mean to replace that with an actual ID of a record, not the literal string `{id}`

Comment: Can you provide the `edit` method code

Comment: @mahmoudMohamedRamadan - edit method code add to the question.

Answer (score 3):

this error means that this line

```
 $prop = Property::find($id);
```

returns `null`, almost because a null value passed to the `$id` variable
due to the missing `$` sign at the action of the edit form, also the variables at the blade should be with double curly braces

**So**

**1- you need to change this line**

```
<form method="POST" action="/admin/properties/update/{id}" class="add_edit_property_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

to this and it should work with you

```
<form method="POST" action="/admin/properties/update/{{$id}}" class="add_edit_property_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

i just added `$` sign and in double curly-braces `{{$id}}`

**2- you need to update your edit method, you need to pass the `$id` parameter to the view**

so, you need to update this method

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        return view('admin.edit_property');

    }
```

to

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        return view('admin.edit_property')->with('id',$id);

    }
```

or to

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        return view('admin.edit_property')->with(compact('id'));

    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I made that edit to the action, but still get the same error. :(

Comment: @webdev1995 please dump `$id` and dump `$prop`  & let us know the dump results

Comment: I ran three var_dumps - on $id, $prop, and $request. I added the results to the question.

Comment: @webdev1995 yes we need also to change `{$id}` to `{{$id}}` in double curly  brackets , answer updated

Comment: I made the change and when trying to load the edit form page, I get this error: `Undefined variable $id`

Comment: This means that `$id` not passed to the view , you need to edit this line `return view('admin.edit_property');` to `return view('admin.edit_property')->with('id',$id);`

Comment: SO I added the `->with('id', $id)` and tried updating a record and got this error: `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'square_feet' cannot be null`

Comment: this error means that you are passing a null value to `square_feet` field, 
so if this property can be nullable , just change it at the DB to `nullable`
 **if not,** 
make validation before  update  & change this input to required input and make sue that this line 
`$prop->square_feet = $request->input('prop_ft');` 
is correctly passing value and there is input with the used name at the mentioned line `prop_ft`